# Split date into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, heidisql

I've been searching for hours but haven't been able to find an answer. I'm hoping somebody might know how to split a date into 3 columns. I have a mysql table that looks like the following

```
Id   Email     First_Name   Last_Name  DOB          Gender
1    yo@1.com  Jack         Smith      1969-03-09   M
2    yo1@1.com Jill         Smith      1982-11-29   F
```

I want the final format to be as follows

```
Id   Email     First_Name Last_Name DOB        DOB_Yr DOB_Mo DOB_Day Gender
1    yo@1.com  Jack       Smith     1969-03-09 1969   03     09      M
2    yo1@1.com Jill       Smith     1982-11-29 1982   11     29      F
```

I have access to HeidiSql and MySQL Workbench. Does anybody how to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you want with leading zeros also, for eg: `03` instead of `3` for month ?

Comment: Dare we ask why? Anyway, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Thank you @MadhurBhaiya for the help. Your solution worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can use various Date functions, like [`YEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year), [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month), and [`DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day), to get the year, month and day value from a MySQL date.

Try:

```
SELECT Id, 
       Email, 
       First_Name, 
       Last_Name, 
       DOB, 
       YEAR(DOB) AS DOB_Yr, 
       MONTH(DOB) AS DOB_Mo, 
       DAY(DOB) AS DOB_Day, 
       Gender 
FROM your_table
```

Incase you want leading 0s in Month and Day (`03` instead of `3`), you can use the [`Lpad()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function. Try the following instead:

```
SELECT Id, 
       Email, 
       First_Name, 
       Last_Name, 
       DOB, 
       YEAR(DOB) AS DOB_Yr, 
       LPAD(MONTH(DOB), 2, '0') AS DOB_Mo, 
       LPAD(DAY(DOB), 2, '0') AS DOB_Day, 
       Gender 
FROM your_table
```